# Jenkins and BitBucket Webhook

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket

I am using `Jenkins` and BitBucket integrations.
I want to trigger a build when a PR is created. I created a webhook on bitbucket it's returning `200` response but no build is getting triggered. I have enabled "Build when a change is pushed to `BitBucket`" option in the build configuration.

Comment: So What is your actual question or the problem?

Comment: I want to trigger a build using webhook from bitbucket cloud.2ndly How bitbucket payload can be used in shell. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use **Generic Webhook Trigger Plugin**. 
You can integrate this plug-in with bitbucket and it will give you payload which contains all the data regarding webhook which you need to process.
here is the link

[Generic+Webhook+Trigger+Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Generic+Webhook+Trigger+Plugin)

Comment: How did you solved with bitbucket?I have same problem!
Thanks!

Comment: we are using Generic webhook trigger pls check the link, let me know if you are facing the issue.